# MongoDB Sharded Cluster Add new secondary node

Tags: mongodb

We have sharded cluster with 2 secondaries on each shard.
Due to space problem one of the secondaries got corrupted.
In order to add new node to the existing shard we have removed data directories on the problematic secondary data node.

Then added new data node using rs.config into existing replica set.
We have around 1.2TB data.
I can see the data folder size is increasing so it proves that its synchronizing from the primary shard.

When I do rs.status() the replica set member shows that the new node is in STARTUP2 mode
Also it shows otptitime as 
"optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),

Data node is able to see primary node as checked from "lastHeartbeatRecv"

We are using Amazon AWS.
Please advise if there are any different method to add new data node with fast sync from Primary as the data is 1.2TB and we have kicked of the sync process 7 days before.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the recent snapshot of the good secondary one into the problematic secondary node after cleaning the data directories. Then add this node into replica set. Let the oplog be applied automatically and synch with primary node. This way synchronization time will be reduced as secondary has to just catch up the backlog from the day when snapshot of the good secondary node is taken.